# What would be the returned values from torch.Torch.size() apart from height and width?

Tags: python, pytorch, size

I'm using a module (SwimIR) for image super resolution based on PyTorch

One of the operations that is done is:

```
b, c, h, w = img_lq.size()

E = torch.zeros(b, c, h*scale_factor, w*scale_factor).type_as(img_lq)
W = torch.zeros_like(E)
```

I.e., getting the tensor shape and creating a new tensor of zeros of the same shape. I'm trying to understand what would be the two assigned variables `b` and `c` returned by the method `size()` apart from `h` and `w` that are height and width respectively.

Looking in [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.size.html), I haven't found anything that could give me a clue about what are those 2 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`torch.Tensor.size`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.size.html) function returns the shape of the tensor. As would accessing `torch.Tensor.shape` directly.

In other words the first line is simply unpacking the dimension sizes of `img_lq` as: `b` (*"batch size"*), `c` (*"channels"*), `h` (*"height"*), and `w` (*"width"*). Of course, this code makes the assumption that img_lq has exactly four dimensions.